# Can I point multiple application servers to different Mongos instances?

Tags: mongodb

I inherited a large production sharded Mongo set up. It appears that there are three Mongos (query router) instances (all look healthy in rs.status()), but the developers are only using one connection string.

I know load balancing them requires session affinity - But is it safe to point some of the app servers to the other Mongos instances?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can. The most current versions of the officially supported drivers will do this for you. You can list the set of mongos processes you'd like the driver to connect to in the mongouri string.

mongodb://host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]]

More information on the mongouri format and options is available in the MongoDB [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).

The current versions of the officially supported drivers will distribute requests evenly across all mongos instances which appear in the mongouri, per the [server selection specification](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-selection-next-generation-mongodb-drivers). Listing more than one mongos in the mongouri is a good idea both for distributing load across the available routing processes, but also to avoid a single point of failure.